# Encrypting SQLite database in Delphi OLEDB

Tags: delphi, sqlite, encryption, odbc, ado

How to use encryption to SQLite DB in Delphi if i'm using [SQLite ODBC Driver](http://www.ch-werner.de/sqliteodbc/).
*I must use ADO components for data access.*

Comment: +1 since I think this is a good question. There is already one good answer by da-soft. Why closing this one? IMHO it is far from vague - on the contrary, this is a good one. Of course, the answer will be generic (no solution on Delphi side - but perhaps it may have been one), but the solution exists.

Comment: why _must_ you use ADO? I can do anything I want with these: https://github.com/stijnsanders/TSQLite

Comment: Yes, i must use only ADO, because in project used other ODBC drivers, for example, data provider for Oracle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I see from ODBC driver source, one of the 2 options:

1. Compile ODBC driver with `WITH_SQLITE_DLLS` defined, so it will use sqlite3.dll. Then provide sqlite3.dll compiled with `SQLITE_HAS_CODEC`.
2. Compile ODBC driver and SQLite engine with `SQLITE_HAS_CODEC` defined. Then link SQLite engine statically with ODBC driver.

`SQLITE_HAS_CODEC` means, that SQLite engine is compiled with build-in codec. By default SQLite has no codec. You can use [SQLCipher](http://sqlcipher.net/) instead of standard SQLite. Or obtain SQLite with [Encryption Extension](http://www.hwaci.com/sw/sqlite/see.html).

Then to connect to encrypted database using ODBC you will need to specify `PWD=xxx` in connection string.

Comment: +1 Pretty good analyze and explanations. Another SQLite port including encryption is [wxSQLite](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wxsqlite).

Comment: Also an option to get SQLite with encryption is to use 3d party libraries. Although TS sayd, it is not possible for him.